# Optional DocuSign editor before sending

Tags: json, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API to generate digital agreements.  So far all has gone well, but I now have a requirement to optionally have the contract sent to a user for editing within DocuSign before it is sent to the signatories.

My existing API calls are fairly simple, just using a template for the document:

`POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes HTTP/1.1`

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "<template_id>",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "person1@company.com",
      "name": "Person One",
      "roleName": "Signatory1"
    },
    {
      "email": "person2@somewhere.com",
      "name": "Person Two",
      "roleName": "Signatory2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to have the same template sent to an editing user to adjust the envelope details before delivering to the signatories.

Anybody had any luck with a similar requirement?

Things I have tried:

- Adding a `compositeTemplates` to the above request with an inline template that has an editor.  This unfortunately removes all of the fields from the document.
- Placing the whole request in `compositeTemplates` with the template selected as a server template, and the recipients in an inline template.  This does not correctly match up the recipient roles to the template roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following composite template to add an Editor in addition to the template roles you have.

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "templateId": "<template_id>"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "person1@company.com",
                            "name": "Person One",
                            "roleName": "Signatory1",
                            "recipientId": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "person2@company.com",
                            "name": "Person Two",
                            "roleName": "Signatory2",
                            "recipientId": "2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "editors": [
                        {
                            "name": "person three",
                            "email": "personthree@company.com",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "routingOrder": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CodingDawg, getting close.  The above still sends to all recipients at once.  Setting the `"routingOrder": "2"` on the two signers results in them not matching against the template roles.

Doing some further experimenting...

Comment: Recipient matching is based on Recipient Role and Routing Order. If there are matches, the recipient information is merged together.  Otherwise a new recipient is created ignoring the template roles.

Comment: Seems so.  The template doesn't have a signing order, but it seems that makes them default to a routing order of 1.  It's working now if I set the editor's routing order to "0" and the signers to "1".  Thanks for your help.  Got me there in the end.  Add those changes in your answer for anyone else looking and I'll give it the green tick, thanks.